# Can input parameters affect SP performance?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I just created this stored procedure that has an `inner join` of two tables: `MyTable` and `MyTable2`. Each of these tables has 5M+ rows.

Apparently, the `inner join` takes over 3 minutes *only if* if the SP receives the @from and @to as input parameters. This is my original SP:

```
aLTER procedure usp_Weird
(      
 @from date,      
 @To date      
)      
as        
--declare @from date = cast(dateadd(day, -5, getdate()) as date)
--declare @to date = cast(dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) as date)
      
      
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#daily') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #daily;       
      
;with cte as      
(      
 SELECT  cast( MyTable.DATETIME as date) AS DATE_Final
   FROM       
   MyTable INNER JOIN MyTable2 
   ON MyTable.DATETIME = MyTable2.DATETIME AND MyTable.Id = MyTable2.Id
  WHERE MyTable.DATETIME BETWEEN @From AND @to      
   AND MyTable2.DATETIME BETWEEN @From AND @to      
) select count(*) from cte
```

The following script takes over 3 minutes to complete:

```
declare @from date = cast(dateadd(day, -5, getdate()) as date)
declare @to date = cast(dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) as date)
exec usp_weird @from, @to;
```

So I simply commented the input parameters and declared them within the SP, like this:

```
aLTER procedure usp_Weird
--(      
--@from date,      
--@To date      
--)      
as        
declare @from date = cast(dateadd(day, -5, getdate()) as date)
declare @to date = cast(dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) as date)
      
      
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#daily') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #daily;       
      
;with cte as      
(      
 SELECT  cast( MyTable.DATETIME as date) AS DATE_Final
   FROM       
   MyTable INNER JOIN MyTable2 
   ON MyTable.DATETIME = MyTable2.DATETIME AND MyTable.Id = MyTable2.Id
  WHERE MyTable.DATETIME BETWEEN @From AND @to      
   AND MyTable2.DATETIME BETWEEN @From AND @to      
) select count(*) from cte
```

The following runs in under one second, every single time:

```
declare @from date = cast(dateadd(day, -5, getdate()) as date)
declare @to date = cast(dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) as date)

exec usp_weird; -- I'm not using @from and @to declared above
```

Now, if I eliminate the INNER JOIN both versions of the SP will run incredibly fast, which leads me to believe that the issue is the combination of the inner join and the input parameters.

My question is: why is the `INNER JOIN` so much slower when the stored procedure runs with the dates as parameters?

What's the difference between having the dates as parameters or declared within the SP?

I also downloaded the `sp_whoisactive` and these are the results:

Executing SP with input parameters:

```
dd hh:mm:ss.mss: 00 00:02:41.820
wait_info: NULL
CPU: 161,821
reads: 10,713,290
```

Executing SP without input parameters:

```
dd hh:mm:ss.mss: 00 00:00:00.026
wait_info: (7ms)CXCONSUMER
CPU: 97
reads: 53
```

Update: I added a nonclustered index of `DATETIME` and `ID` MyTable2. Now both SPs are equally fast.

*BUT* This doesn't explain why this performance deficiency is only apparent when the SP is called with parameters.

Comment: almost certainly a cached plan - try adding `option (recompile)` to the query that uses the params in the sproc

Comment: I had already tried `EXEC sp_recompile 'usp_Totals'`. It didn't affect its slow performance.

Comment: I just added `WITH RECOMPILE` in the SP. Didn't do much.

Comment: sp_recompile will recompile the sproc once whereas `option (recompile)` will recompile it every time it's called - alternatively you could try `option (optimize for unknown)`

Comment: `with recompile` is not the same as `option (recompile)` the ladder often remedies bad plan caching the former usually doesn't for whatever reason

Comment: If the `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` query hint doesn't help, try 1) updating stats and 2) use `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` instead. The latter is the same as local variables.

Comment: If the issue were the underlying query, then it would be slow with or without parameters.

Comment: Without parameters it runs in under a second. With parameters it never finishes  executing.

Comment: I've added the stored procedure to the question.